# TIKA - Compute Content-Encoding of a document

Tags: apache-tika, content-encoding, tika-server

I'm using Tika 1.26 in order to extract metadata of a document.

I first gave a try to the Tika Server and then I switched to programmatic API. Nevertheless, even if the documentation states that the `Content-Encoding` of a document should be returned via the [/meta API](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TIKA/TikaServer#TikaServer-MetadataResource) or the MetadataParser, the property is not actually returned.

I found that the API that actually returns a Charset is the [CharsetDetector](https://tika.apache.org/1.26/api/org/apache/tika/parser/txt/CharsetDetector.html), but I don't know how to invoke this same API via the Tika Server.
I don't have any clue right now.

Can someone point me out what's the correct way to model this use case or if I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: What kind of documents are you passing to Apache Tika? You'll only ever get the encoding of text-based formats, never with binary formats

Comment: I'm trying with PDF files. The problem I see is actually on the extracted text.
Since I cannot detect the encoding during before executing text extraction I'm not able to see some parts of the text extracted properly. So your suggestion is to extract the text and then get the encoding from the text extracted?

Comment: Text in PDF doesn't really have an encoding, that's only a thing with plain text files. Could your PDF be OCR'd? See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TIKA/Troubleshooting+Tika#TroubleshootingTika-PDFTextProblems

Comment: mh, the pdfs I'm using actually contains text and not images (I don't know how it has been originally created but I can select text in that). Anyway I tried your suggestion and it seems that some of the unicode characters are not recognised, in particular some characters with the caron (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caron) that are reported as U+008D, U+008E and U+009D which are special characters of the OS. What I don't know now is if these chars are wrong in the original file or there is any other problem.

Comment: So probably nothing to do with the encoding, at the end. more a problem with the original PDF?

Comment: You'd be best off asking on the Apache Tika users mailing list - many more Tika + PDF experts there than here! https://lists.apache.org/list.html?user@tika.apache.org